# spring camel test using multiple contexts

Tags: apache-camel

I have two camel contexts (A and B) at different xml using Spring. When I load just one context my junit works, but when a I try to load both contexts the Endpoint inject fail running junit.

So, someone have a sample how to use Test using multiple context with spring camel?

Spring Test

```java
public class BaseSpringTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport
{
    protected AbstractXmlApplicationContext createApplicationContext()
    {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("camel-config.xml");
    }
}
```

My file `camel-config.xml`

```xml
<beans>
 <context:annotation-config/>
 <import resource="classpath:camel-test-dao.xml" />
 <import resource="classpath:camel-contextA.xml"/>
 <import resource="classpath:camel-contextB.xml"/>
</beans>
```

My contexts:

```xml
<camelContext xmlns="camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="contextA"> 
 ...
</camelContext>
<camelContext xmlns="camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="contextB"> 
...
</camelContext>
```

My unit test, failing at inject `Endpoint`:

```java
@EndpointInject(uri = "direct:myroute", context="contextB")
private Endpoint eFooTest;
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.camel.spring.GenericBeansException: Error post processing bean: com.mycompany.test.FooTest; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(CamelBeanPostProcessor.java:154)
  at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestSupport.postProcessTest(CamelSpringTestSupport.java:62)
  at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.doSetUp(CamelTestSupport.java:319)
  at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.setUp(CamelTestSupport.java:238)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
  at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
  at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
  at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.camel.impl.CamelPostProcessorHelper.matchContext(CamelPostProcessorHelper.java:84)
  at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor$1.doWith(DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor.java:181)
  at org.apache.camel.util.ReflectionHelper.doWithFields(ReflectionHelper.java:73)
  at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor.injectFields(DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor.java:168)
  at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor.java:82)
  at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(CamelBeanPostProcessor.java:148)
  ... 31 more
```

Apparently there is a bug at CamelBeanPostProcessor, when there are more one context a null value is returned!

> if (contexts != null && contexts.size() == 1) {

```java
@XmlTransient
private final DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor delegate = new DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor() {
    @Override
    public CamelContext getOrLookupCamelContext() {
        if (camelContext == null) {
            if (camelId != null) {
                LOG.trace("Looking up CamelContext by id: {} from Spring ApplicationContext: {}", camelId, applicationContext);
                camelContext = applicationContext.getBean(camelId, CamelContext.class);
            } else {
                // lookup by type and grab the single CamelContext if exists
                LOG.trace("Looking up CamelContext by type from Spring ApplicationContext: {}", applicationContext);
                Map<String, CamelContext> contexts = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(CamelContext.class);
                if (contexts != null && contexts.size() == 1) {
                    camelContext = contexts.values().iterator().next();
                }
            }
        }
        return camelContext;
    }
```

`Camel 2.16.2`
`Spring 4.1.5`
`JDK 1.7`
`JDK 1.8`

Comment: add a 'camelId' to your beanPostProcessor xml element, or don't use it, and let the default beanprocessor be registered ?

Comment: This code is the default beanpostprocessor [DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-spring/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spring/CamelBeanPostProcessor.java) isn't my :)

Comment: i wasn't speaking about the default implementation, but the default configuration. by default, in the xml configuration, for each <camelContext> element, camel define a beanPostProcessor initialized with the property "camelId" set to the camelContext id. in the code you shown, you'll see that when camelId != null, then the camelContext is looked up in the applicationContext

Comment: Thanks @JérémieB for you help. I got. 

I have my spring contexts configured this way:

**<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="contextA">**
**<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="contextB">**

And when I try to get the endpoint from a context I cannot.

**@EndpointInject(uri = "direct:myroute", context="contextB")**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Jorge-c, but using routeContext we continuous having just one single CamelContext.

To use multiply contexts at unit test don't use CamelSpringTestSupport, there are a bug.

```java
public class BaseSpringTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {...}
```

Use "@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)"

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/camel-my-root-spring-config.xml")
public class BaseSpringJUnit4 
{
  @EndpointInject(uri = "direct:myroute", context="contextB")
  private Endpoint eFooTest;
}
```

This works! **Doesn't forget to put explicitilly context="contextB" in the endpoint annotation**

`Camel 2.16.2`
`Spring 4.1.5`
`JDK 1.7`
`JDK 1.8`

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a while as well. Finally I managed a workaround which allows me to use the original routes xml files used in production but combined into a single camel context to be able to use it for testing. This way I'm able to inject mocks for bean endpoints and check the complete process by asserting on the mocks.

There are two different bundles. One from invoicing and another for emailing. The routes orchestrate the process.

First I externalized the routes on the production xml files. Spring context (**invoicing-spring-context.xml**) and routes (**invoicing-routes.xml**) file for invoicing bundle:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>
    ...
    <camelContext id="invoicingCamelContext"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <routeContextRef ref="invoicingRoutes"/>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>
    <routeContext id="invoicingRoutes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="planner" autoStartup="true">
            <from uri="quartz://planner?cron=0+0+23+16+*+?" />
            <to uri="direct:invoicing" />
        </route>

        <route id="invoicing" autoStartup="true">
            <from uri="direct:invoicing?exchangePattern=InOut" />
            <to uri="bean:invoicer?method=generateInvoices" />
            <to uri="direct-vm:emailing" />
        </route>
    </routeContext>
</beans>
```

Spring context (**emailing-spring-context.xml**) and routes (**emailing-routes.xml**) for emailing bundle:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>
    ...
    <camelContext id="emailingCamelContext"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <routeContextRef ref="emailingRoutes"/>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>
    <routeContext id="emailingRoutes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="emailing" autoStartup="true">
            <from uri="direct-vm:emailing" />
            <to uri="bean:emailer?method=createEmails" />
            <to uri="bean:emailer?method=sendEmails" />
        </route>
    </routeContext>
</beans>
```

---

Then for testing purposes I created another spring context (**complete-process-test-spring-context.xml**) which imports both routes files:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>
    ...
    <camelContext id="completeProcessTestCamelContext"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">      
        <routeContextRef ref="invoicingRoutes"/>
        <routeContextRef ref="emailingRoutes"/>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

And the test class looks like:

```java
public class CompleteProcessTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {
    @Test
    public void completeProcess() {
        ...

        invoicerMock.generateInvoices(EasyMock.isA(Exchange.class));
        emailerMock.createEmails(EasyMock.isA(Exchange.class));
        emailerMock.sendEmails(EasyMock.isA(Exchange.class));

        EasyMock.replay(invoicerMock);
        EasyMock.replay(emailerMock);

        this.template.requestBody(this.context.getEndpoint("direct://invoicing"), "");

        EasyMock.verify(invoicerMock);
        EasyMock.verify(emailerMock);
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/META-INF/spring/invoicing-routes.xml",
                "classpath:/META-INF/spring/emailing-routes.xml",
                "classpath:/META-INF/spring/complete-process-test-spring-context.xml");
    }

    ...
}
```